# Response streamed [200 OK]> is not JSON serializable stream image python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, bing-maps, bing

I am looking for a way to serve some images from the bing map without sharing the URL (because it contains the secret key) and return it to the client (without saving to disk first).  I'm using this method from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/118/)

```
def get_stream_from_url(url):
    req = requests.get(url, stream = True)
    return Response(stream_with_context(req.iter_content()), content_type = req.headers['content-type'])
```

I use it in another method, where I generate a list with those info for those image, so basically I wan to put the  sream response inside the json as a value of key `url`:

```
   def images_data_and_url(self, data):
        results = []
        for i in range(1, 13):
            image = {}
            description = data['description']
            url = self.get_stream_from_url(data['url'])
            tile = {"description": description
                    "url": url}
           results.append(image)
        print results
        return json.dumps(results)
```

EDIT: 
If I print the results I have this:

```
<type 'list'>: [{'description': ' this is an example', 'url': <Response streamed [200 OK]>}, {'description': ' this is an example', 'url': <Response streamed [200 OK]>} , {'description': ' this is an example', 'url': <Response streamed [200 OK]>}, {'description': ' this is an example', 'url': <Response streamed [200 OK]>}, {'description': ' this is an example', 'url': <Response streamed [200 OK]>}, {'description': ' this is an example', 'url': <Response streamed [200 OK]>}, {'description': ' this is an example', 'url': <Response streamed [200 OK]>}, {'description': ' this is an example', 'url': <Response streamed [200 OK]>},{'description': ' this is an example', 'url': <Response streamed [200 OK]>}, {'description': ' this is an example', 'url': <Response streamed [200 OK]>}, {'description': ' this is an example', 'url': <Response streamed [200 OK]>}, {'description': ' this is an example', 'url': <Response streamed [200 OK]>}]
```

If I do like this I get this error

```
<Response streamed [200 OK]> is not JSON serializable
```

This because of the function `get_stream_from_url` returns a response :/ My problem is that I don't know how to send it in another way?

In HTML I get the data and assign per the data for each image like this:

```
<img class="image1 " data-description="The description" src="">
```

Can somebody help me, how to encode the stream so I can send it as with the JSON data?

Comment: What looks it loíke when you do `print(results)` before the `return` in your `images_data_and_url` function?

Comment: Thanks, I see. As you may have noted, the URLs are wron, so I would start there. Maybe you're doing it too complicated, and that's why it's breaking...

Comment: @linusg url are okay cause I tested it?

Comment: No. All the URLs are `<Response streamed [200 OK]>`, which is **not** a valid URL.

Comment: @linusg is possible to assign this `stream_with_context(req.iter_content()), content_type = req.headers['content-type']` to a variable and return it instead of a response ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124419/discussion-between-ritchie-and-linusg).

Comment: Just updated the code for Python 3 compatibility...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flask` is overkill for this. I've created a library called `wsinfo`, which is available here: https://github.com/linusg/wsinfo.

With it, the code is as simple as:

```
import base64
import wsinfo
import sys


def html_image(data, content_type):
    if sys.version.startswith("3"):
        from io import BytesIO
        f = BytesIO(data.encode())
    else:
        from StringIO import StringIO
        f = StringIO(data)

    encoded = base64.b64encode(f.read())
    return "data:{};base64,{}".format(content_type, encoded)

url = "http://t0.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a1210223003.jpeg?g=854&mkt=en-US"
w = wsinfo.Info(url)
img = html_image(w.content, w.content_type)

with open("out.html", "w") as html:
    html.write('<img class="image1" data-description="The description" src="{}" />'.format(img))
```

The code runs with both Python 2 and 3, and results in an HTML file called `out.html`, where the image is embedded.

Comment: You really saved my day! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to hide a Bing Maps key. Anyone can create on and use it under the free terms of use. As such there is little incentive for them to steal your key. In majority of cases where a key appeared to be stolen, the root cause was code being handed off that contained the key or the key being posted in code samples in forum posts. The user of the key usually were unaware of the key in the code. The Bing Maps team is able to track these situations and resolve them as needed. That said it rarely occurs. Generally, when someone wants to steal a Bing Maps key, they just use the key from the Bing Maps website.